# jQuery get value of n-th element

Tags: jquery

Good day. I used search but didn't find the answer I was looking for, I think this is a common question.

Is there any solution to get value of n-th element via jQuery?

Here is simple example:
Imagine that we have n inputs with same class. The easiest way to get value of n-th, as I thought `$(".some_class").get(n-th).val()` the simplest way. But when we use `get()`, it returns

> Object #HTMLInputElement

So after using on it `val()` we got error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLInputElement has no method 'val'.

Is there any solution how use only jQuery methods in this situation?

Comment: pls share ur jquery code

Comment: @ Delphian, sure
shortcode += "[toggle title='"+$('.toggle_title').get(i-1).val()+"' open='yes']";

Comment: see more about :eq element http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: `$("some_class:eq(n-th)").val();` value of `n-th` starts from 0

Comment: @Tushar Gupta, sorry for confuse. Previouse code contains **for(var i=1; i<=$('.toggle_title').length; i++)** so indexes should be decreased by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eq` instead:

```
$(".some_class").eq(n-th).val()
```

[`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) constructs a new jQuery object from the element you've specified within the set.

Answer (score 2):

You would get list of nth elements using nth child, so use val on one of them

```
$(".some_class input:nth-child(2)").eq(0).val()
```

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected,
>   [reference](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

If you just want to get nth input within class .some_class you can simply use eq()

```
$(".some_class").eq(0).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eq with jQuery

$('selector').eq('number')

Answer (score 1):

```
$("element:nth-child(1)").val();
$("element:nth(0)").val();
$("element:eq(0)").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

In a line use the code as :

```
$('container').eq('n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery().get() method returns the actual HTML Element, not a jQuery object (hence it has no .val() method).  You need to use .value or you need to retrieve the index using [].

E.G.

```
 $(".some_class").get(n-th).value;
```

OR

```
 $(".some_class")[n-th].val();
```

Comment: $(".some_class")[n-th].val(); returns html object too.